# Airflow:How do I use PyMySQL with MySQL Hook?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, airflow, pymysql

I am trying to use MySQL in Apache Airflow. I already use `PymySQL` to query MySQL databases and did not have `MySQLDb` installed. Thus I got the error:

```
 from airflow.hooks.mysql_hook import MySqlHook
  File "/anaconda3/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/hooks/mysql_hook.py", line 15, in <module>
    import MySQLdb
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

If I go into `mysql_hook.py` class I already see they are using `MySQLDB`

```
import MySQLdb
import MySQLdb.cursors
```

What alternative I have other than importing `pymysql` manually instead of in a hook?

I am using Python 3.6

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In order for the MySQL hook to work in Airflow, you need to install the MySQL extra package. If you have installed Airflow with pip, then the following command will do:

```
pip install apache-airflow[mysql]
```

This will install the [mysqlclient](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python) package, which is the one required here.